# When enabling MSAA, artifacts appear and texture lookups fail on edges

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, msaa

On the edges of my cubes, lines with RGBA 0, 0, 0, 0 appear as texture lookups on that position fail. I have colored the texture lookups that failed magenta in my fragment shader.

Should I render to a texture first, bind it to a quad and perform the MSAA afterwards instead of per cube?

Maybe it samples pixels that are not filled yet.

[image]

Comment: Yes. That will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: Binding to a quad first does not help. Maybe it needs to know the vertices to perform MSAA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` instead of `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER` solved the issue.